# How could I make halftones like the example in this image

Tags: games, halftone

How could I make these halftones like the example shown here.

[image]

Comment: This is one of those rare occasions where it literally is just a filter (effect) that you pick from a list. If you search google or youtube for halftone tutorials, you're bound to find millions of them. Is there something specific you're stuck with?

Comment: also please don't ask opinion questions... Better rephrase it to something more objective. Check [ask] for more help on what kind of questions to ask here, and the [tour] for how the site works.

Answer (score 4):

This would really depend on the software you are using.  Since you haven't mentioned any, I'd suggest a vector image editor. For example this can be done in Inkscape which is free and Open Source. Here are the basic steps.

1. Create a square and fill it with a gradient
2. Create a black filled dot, align it to the upper left of the square. Then use the Tiled Clones function, Trace tab, to create the pattern
3. Change the colour of the clone source as required
4. Group then Rotate 45°
5. Use a shape as a clipping mask
6. Finished result, I also added a copy of the circle on top for a thick stroke around the circle.

[image]

One of the nice things about using tiled clones in Inkscape is that you can edit the clone source, for example changing its colour, or even changing its size to affect the density of the halftone pattern. Also this is not just some raster effect, it's fully vector, so it will scale nicely without degradation in quality.

[image]

If you need more detailed help, there are tutorials using this Inkscape feature on youtube. [Here's one example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5qiZ-kX3dM)

Comment: really a wonderful technique.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2D advertisement illustration of a game. It's not a screenshot of an actual game action. Halftoned areas are filled shapes where the fill is a vector halftone pattern. Essentially the filled shape acts like a clipping mask.

I guess the artist had a collection of ready to use vector patterns, but one can also make them in Illustrator or Inkscape. Ready to use patterns need only scaling, coloring and rotation.

Constant density dot patterns are trivial to make, but gradients are tricky.

In Illustrator vector gradient halftone patterns can be made by blending or by using a paid plugin. At least Astute's Phantasm can do it.

In Inkscape one can use extension Interpolate which resembles Blending in Illustrator. Another possibility is to tile dots by having scaling ON. The third possibility is to use the tracking property of tiling. With it the tiled dots are scaled by the brightness of the underlying image. The underlying image can be a gradient.

An example of making a gradient in Illustrator

1. Draw 2 circles, align them to the same horizontal line

[image]

2. Make a blending between the circles to get equally spaced intermediate versions:

[image]

3. Make a duplicate by moving the stripe downwards and by holding the Alt key. As well you can use Object > Transform > Move > Copy. Repeat the copying by clicking several times Ctrl+D

[image]

Blending should be expanded if you want to adjust some dots individually. Rotating, scaling and applying a clipping mask to whole pattern is possible without expanding. We expand it for easy recoloring.

Scaling all dots in the pattern without moving the dots is possible by ungrouping the pattern, selecting all and applying Object > Transform > Transform Each > Scale.

4. Select all. Apply Object > Blend > Expand. The dot stripes become groups of separate dots. Select all, ungroup and group again to have a single group of dots. Rotate it to a good angle, change the fill color and insert the shape which should be filled with the dots:

[image]

5. Select the group and the shape, apply Object > Clipping Mask > Make:

[image]

As you see, the clipping obeys strictly the given path. The same happens in your example. If one wants to prevent splitting the dots at the edge, a totally different method is needed. That case is presented in GDSE elsewhere, but I skip it.